# SOLR schema is Invalid?

Tags: solr

I have been tweaking my SOLR 5.4 schema and I have noticed this behavior:

If I have `_path` defined in my `schema.xml`, I do **not** see `_path_sm` (or `_path`) in my raw SOLR index.  However, if I **remove** the `_path` definition from my `schema.xml`, then I correctly see `_path_sm` in my index.

The offending field is:

```xml
<field name="_path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

And the field looks like this in SOLR:

```xml
<arr name="_path_sm">
    <str>11111111111111111111111111111111</str>
    <str>0de95ae441ab4d019eb067441b7c2450</str>
    <str>3156c74fd8334b8f86815a17ebe69998</str>
    <str>05e49a575ece46e98b73ce7f3fedc78d</str>
    <str>fd17e8226ec8435ea522d32f986bb8e1</str>
    <str>f9ce8111622a45e0b9cf2f88ea627c06</str>
    <str>c7f77608398e457297890077a5500c73</str>
</arr>
```

Has anyone else noticed this behavior?  Is there an elegant solution (besides just removing the field from my schema)?

Comment: Do you have more context as to why you're trying to add a specific definition for "_path"?

Feels like you're running into some functionality related to the dynamicfields defined later in the schema.

Comment: @Laver- I never thought of it this way.  Should I not pre-define the sitecore built in fields?

Comment: This would require further investigation. I didn't submit an answer as it was just conjecture. The field named _path_sm will be based on the *_sm DynamicField, Sitecore is using this field to store a field named "_path" that requires a multi-valued string format, so it uses the pre-defined DynamicField.

I'm assuming that somewhere within the indexing process Sitecore or Lucene is noticing that an _path field already exists in the Schema and is trying to insert it's data into your field.

Answer (score 4):

Please, verify that your attribute "stored" is set to true:

```xml
<field name="_path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

I had the behavior you mentioned when the stored attribute was set to false. Check you have that value set on all schemas

Comment: Yep, it is already set that way.  It only works when I omit the entire <field /> though.

Comment: You'll need to rebuild the index after changing this value to force the field to recrawl as a stored field rather than an unstored field.